# "key_len" column is more important or "rows" column in the result of EXPLAIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have executed a query with two different kind of indexes. Here is the result of them:

**First kind of index:**

[image]

**Second kind of index:**

[image]

As you see, the first one has a bigger number in the *"key_len"* column. And the second one has a bigger number in the *"rows"* column.

I want to know, which one is more efficient ?

**Note:** My dataset is pretty small.

Comment: On small datasets, you do not need to worry about performance.  On larger data sets, I would say that rows in more important.

Comment: There's not enough information here to determine which would be more efficient. What's important is cardinality and selectivity. An index improves performance by eliminating (very quickly) vast swaths of rows that need to be checked. Efficient query plans typically make effective use of indexes, if there are equality predicates on several columns in the same table, we tend to prefer indexes containing those columns as leading columns. We tend to get getter performance from plans that examine fewer rows. And use inline views (derived tables) only where required, due to the performance overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:  `Rows` is more important than `key_len`.

With those tiny numbers, you can't predict much.  Here are some tips:

`INT` is 4 bytes, `BIGINT` is 8 bytes.  `NULL` adds 1.  So I guess key_len=9 is a NULLable BIGINT?  (It would really help if you provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT...`.)  key_len=5 might be a nullable INT.  Use `NOT NULL` wherever appropriate.

`VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8` will weigh in as key_length=767.

`Rows` (3 or 4) on the `<derived>` table is an exact count, since `EXPLAIN` evaluated it.  `Rows` on other lines are approximate; sometimes they are off (either direction) by a factor of 2, maybe more.

`eq_ref` `Rows=1` is common for essentially looking up by a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key.  So that is likely to be exact, except when the row is missing.

A crude (very crude) way to judge an `EXPLAIN` is to multiply the numbers in the `Rows` column.  In your cases, you get 9 and 32.  But I would not jump to the conclusion that the 9 is faster than 32.  If it were 9000000 versus 32000, then I might jump to a conclusion.

The most common mistake for a novice is not understanding that `INDEX(last_name, first_name)` is often more performant than `INDEX(last_name) , INDEX(first_name)`.